# Import Data Between Servers with Different Version

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2000, generate-scripts

I need to transfer data from sql 2012 to 2000 so I decide to create a file of insert using "Generate Script" in sql 2012 then Execute it in sql 2000.
But one of the columns DataType is Date; The Sql 2012 generates Date like this:

```
CAST(0x13FC0A00 AS DateTime)
```

But SQL 2000 throw Syntax error when executing the above code

> Syntax error converting datetime from binary/varbinary string.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in SQL Management Studio going

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `SQL Server Object Explorer` -> `Scripting`

Set "Script for server version" to "SQL Server 2000".
Then re-generate the scripts.